# Why is the same group of cluster's datapoints falling far away or scattered in Kmeans clustering?

Tags: matplotlib, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a doubt which is also been asked me plenty times in my meetings where I am successful in failing to answer it.. I am hoping that you can help me out to know the insight of this question.

I had used kmeans clustering in my project for clustering numerous documents for the respective problem areas. I also used matplotlib to plot the coordinates of the data point. More often the data points which falls to the same cluster are scattered or far away from other documents or datapoints which falls in the same group of cluster. The question generally people ask me is, if the document or the datapoint is from the same cluster/group then it needs to be closer to each other, Why is that not happening with respect to the documents thats of the same group/cluster.

How do I convince them, Sometimes I go Clueless what to say them.

Adding to the same question,  I had no control on the formation of the cluster, but as a domain expert in my field, I very well know the problem areas the documents belongs to. So how do I configure/cluster this thousands of documents into only those problem areas accurately using Kmeans or any other clustering machinisium or by playing around with the hyperparameters. Kindly help me.[image]

I Have take reference from http://brandonrose.org/clustering

[image]

Father, New york, brother is a cluster which is in purple. If it belongs to the same cluster then it all needs to be at one side plot screen closer to each other. Why is it scattered everywhere in the plot screen. Thats what is also happening in my case.

Comment: In my experience, k-means on text does not work too well. **Never trust** the result. Use it at most to give you an *idea*  what is there, because usually at least 50% of points are in the wrong clusters.

Comment: ok, In that case what algorithm suites well for text. Let broader my problem requirement. I have thousands of documents/problems from different souces like bugzilla, socialcast, salesforce etc... I want to cluster this documents or PR into a sharp problem area. Say for example In JAVA there are many problems people face everyday and they post their problems, I need to take all this documents and cluster them into specific area of problem, like nullpointerexception should all come in one cluster and collection related issues should come in other cluster. What algo suites well to cluster this.

Comment: I doubt any clustering will be able to do that. Because you used multiple data sources, you are more likely to see clusters corresponding to: bugzilla, socialcast, salesforce. That would be a successful clustering, but useless for you.

Comment: Hi @Anony-Mousse after you said, I am running the kmeans cluster with respect to each datasource. Data from socialcast is ran seperetely without clubbing with bugzilla or saleforce. But still I see the cluster are forming based some words that ideally shouldn't be the cluster(like for example its giving "day","exist","around","info) these are not my problem areas. How do I preprocess the data to get some meaningful clusters. I have removed the stopwords and unwanted words also, as and when I remove the unwanted words it given an error saying increase the max_df or decrease the min_df in tfidf.

Comment: I don't have any positive experiences with clustering text, sorry.

Comment: Thats Ok, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide very little information about your data, therfore this answer is a bit speculative. But I am quite sure that your data points have more than two components and that you do the k-means clustering in an at least three-dimensional space. Then you use some kind of projection to display them in 2D. Because of the projection, points that are originally far away from each other seem to be close together. The 2D plot says little about the neighborhood relations in the original, higher-dimensional space.

Comment: I refered this link to solve my problem 
http://brandonrose.org/clustering 
Even here I see that the movie of a particular cluster are scattered away. I will also upload the image above. I you see the cluster name is Father, New York, brother which is in purple and those data points are scattered every where in the plot.  why is that, If its all of the same cluster then it needs to be closer right.

Comment: @Niteshkumar: The linked document confirms my assumption that the actual clustering is done in a high-dimensional vector space. In this space, the points of a cluster are actually close together. The diagram you show is just a two-dimensional visualization of this space.

Comment: ok, but why is the two-dimensional visualization of datapoints falling under same cluster is very far. The reason I am asking is, I am really feeling very difficult to explain in my meeting. Is there any possible way to explain the high dimension vector space and why this datapoints are far away to the business people. It will be great if you explain me with some analogy and in-depth.
And Thank you very much for your time and explaination that you have done so far.

Comment: @Niteshkumar: Say you have 4 points in 3D: A=(10,0,0), B=(20,0,0), C=(11,0,1000) and D=(21,0,1000). Obviously the clusters would be {A,B} and {C,D}. Now you project them to 2D by removing the 3rd coordinate: A'=(10,0), B'=(20,0), C'=(11,0) and D'=(21,0). Now {A',C'} and {B',D'} are close together.

Comment: Wow Thanks a lot @FrankPuffer. This will really help me a lot.

Comment: Hi @Frank, I am running the kmeans cluster with respect to each datasource. Data from socialcast is ran seperetely without clubbing with bugzilla or saleforce. But still I see the cluster are forming based some words that ideally shouldn't be the cluster(like for example its giving "day","exist","around","info) these are not my problem areas. How do I preprocess the data to get some meaningful clusters. I have removed the stopwords and unwanted words also, as and when I remove the unwanted words it given an error saying increase the max_df or decrease the min_df in tfidf. –